# Double verification emails sent from Cognito upon updating user email address

Tags: java, angular, email, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Cognito for user management in my application. The userpool is configured that the users login with a unique username and a password, and that multiple users can have the same email addess. I am using Amplify built-in components for authentification.

The problem I can't seem to resolve, are double verification mesages upon updating user email. When an an email is chaged CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute is triggered, and when user wants to verify the changed email CustomMessage_VerifyUserAttribute is triggered. I have a custom lambda function that listens for these triggers among others and sends corresponding emails based on the action user is trying to perform: login, verify email, reset password etc.

So if a user modifies his email address, CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute is triggered and the user recieves an email with the following (default) message "Please verify your account and enter the following verification code to reset your password: xxxxxx". However, when this user loggs in, amplify recognises that the user is in the "verifyContact" state, and displays the screen you can see below.

[image]

The user has two options:

1. to skip the verification, or
2. to select the only attribute that awaits verification and click on "verify" button.

Clicking on the "verify" button triggers CustomMessage_VerifyUserAttribute and sends yet another email to the user. The user is redirected to the following screen.

[image]

The second screen shows where user is supposed to input newly sent code (from the second email). So the user has absolutely no need for the first email (and code) that is sent automatically when the email is updated. I have tried to find a way to avoid sending the email, but have not found a good solution. Congito won't let you override the message in lambda without sending the confirmation code in it, which is completely unnecessary since there is no place where user can input it. I don't want to disable email verification, or set email_verified to true upon updating.

Do you have any suggestions what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing the same problem, a workaround is to update email_verified field twice. When updating the email, set email_verified to true. This will prevent Cognito from sending and email on CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute. Then in a separate user attribute update request update only email_verified field to false. This will set the user to "verifyContact" state and request email verification on login.